# My width calculations don't match pixels

Tags: html, css

I have an outer and inner div. Both are positioned relative.

The outer div is 593px wide (by measurement, but created by percent).

The inner div width, allowing for 20px padding on each side, should be 553px wide so that it matches the width of its parent outer div. But I want the actual value to be a %.

553/593 x 100 = **93.25%**  -- But that did not work, it was slightly wide.
The value that actually made the inner div match the outer div was: **92%**

Why?

Comment: Without the required markup to answer the question, the best answer is that you did it wrong.

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS to the question.

Comment: you're dealing with discrete values - pixels. there are no "partial pixels", so the browser will round your percentages to an integer value. can't remember what the rounding rules are, but you can't have a width of (say) `50.4 pixels`. pixels cannot be broken up, so you get `50` or `51` for the on-screen width.

Comment: ...and some browsers round up and some round down...just to confuse matters further.

Comment: I usually do show markup, but I thought this was pretty straightforward...the last two comments basically answered my question, thanks.

Comment: You need to post your solution so others can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use the value of 92% for the inner div. I assume the difference from my calculated value is due to rounding. Going forward I will use the same procedure of calculating + visual adjustment.